# How can I change the background color of the button when it is pressed/down?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom button and I would like to remove the darker color/shadow/background color when the button state is pressed down/clicked, so it it matches the background color of the button already. So it looks like no one pressed it but it still has a click event attached to it.

I was wondering how can I do that for Xamarin.Forms Android?

I already have a custom renderer setup but I need something like

```
Control.SetBackgroundColor(Color, ButtonState.Down)
```

so it'll be that color on the down state. Idk, if there's way to do this for Android?

Also, I am using C# for my view.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a StateListDrawable for this, where you define each state in one Drawable and assign that as the background for the Button.

You would define a XML drawable like this, using a different image for each state:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_img" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hovered_img" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/focused_img" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_img"/>    
</selector>
```

Then you would assign this drawable to the button in your layout:

```xml
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/statelistdrawable" />
```

You can also create this in C#:

```
var drawable = new StateListDrawable();
drawable.AddState(new[] {Android.Resource.Attribute.StateFocused},
                      Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.focused));
```

Then set it as background:

```
var myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.Background = drawable;
```

State should now be reflected on the button.

Comment: Opps, just figured out what you meant. One more question, can my drawable be a color instead of an image? And what if, the color of my button, I want it to be the background color of the current page it's on... so it's sort of a dynamic color? This would not work. Thanks!

Comment: @Cheesebaron - it looks like your answer is for Xamarin for Android, not Xamarin Forms. Is this what the question is asking for?  If so, we need to remove the Xamarin.Forms tag, surely?

Comment: He has the Android tag. Hence the Android answer. He says he has a custom renderer, hence he can use this code in his custom renderer to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code from the Xamarin Forum link [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/156184/#Comment_156184). I have not personally tried it but it looks like it could be used to do what you want including using a dynamic color. Maybe something like this (I wrote some of the code from memory so let me know if it does not work):

Forms:

```
public class FancyButton : Button {

    /// <summary>
    /// The color pressed down color property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty PressedDownColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PressedDownColor), typeof(Color), typeof(FancyButton), default(Color));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the pressed down color.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The color to change to when the button is pressed down string.</value>
    public Color PressedDownColor {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(PressedDownProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressedDownProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Droid:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App2.FancyButton), typeof(FancyButtonAndroid))]
namespace App2.Droid {

    public class FancyButtonAndroid : ButtonRenderer {

        private Color _pressedDownColor;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e) {

            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Android.Widget.Button thisButton = Control as Android.Widget.Button;

            FancyButton formsButton = (FancyButton)Element;

            _pressedDownColor = formsButton.PressedDownColor;

            thisButton.Touch += (object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e2) => {
                if (e2.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
                    thisButton.SetBackgroundColor(_pressedDownColor.ToAndroid());
                } else if (e2.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
                    thisButton.SetBackgroundColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Default.ToAndroid());
                }
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the element property changed event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender</param>
        /// <param name="e">The event arguments</param>
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            FancyButton formsButton = Element as FancyButton;

            if(formsButton != null && e.PropertyName == FancyButton.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName) {
                _pressedDownColor = formsButton.PressedDownColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```